How to get MDAnalysis to recognise atom labels as elements?
I am trying to use a program called CageCavityCalc to analyse some AIMD output. Among other packages, CageCavityCalc uses the Python library MDAnalysis to facilitate this. Unfortunately, it appears that MDAnalysis was not written with chemists in mind and, as a result, does not recognise elements from the periodic table. From their documentation:

When atom atom_types are guessed, they represent the atom element.
Atom types are always guessed from the atom name. MDAnalysis follows
biological naming conventions, where atoms named “CA” are much more
likely to represent an alpha-carbon than a calcium atom. This guesser
is still relatively fragile for non-traditionally biological atom
names.

Unfortunately, my systems involve argon and, apparently, biologists are unfamiliar with this element.
I have been searching for ages now and can find no mention of any way to tell MDAnalysis to use standard periodic table definitions of atoms as opposed to biological ones. Has anyone else come across this problem? Is there a keyword or option or any workaround to tell MDAnalysis to use periodic table definitions of atoms instead of biologists' labels?

MDAnalysis is designed to work with protein/ligands files, so, yes, it is designed to "understand" chemistry. Did you try to use PDB files?

@Camps Yep, it's a PDB file that I'm using as my input
